# Remove Dulicate Row when Grid is bind with sepcific condition

Tags: asp.net

I want delete duplicate some rows from data table with which is coming on specific date.I have write code.

I have table which holds package name and date. Then i want which package is coming on same date they will remove. How i can do it. My code is given below:

```
Column Name Is : vsPackageName
Second column : Date
```

I am not able to put date column.

PROBLEM

This time package is delete from table but all dates.And What I want is If packages is commming on 14 AUG 2013 3 time.Then it should remove and show only one row, not three row

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

use `distinct` in your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();//your datatable
                DataView view = new DataView(dt);
                DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "vsPackageName", "Date");
                //GridView1 is suppose to your gridview
                GridView1.DataSource = distinctValues;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```